# How can i resize the entire flex app just like acrobat connect?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

ive been pondering how to create the same type of resizing that acrobat connect does. i did read the documentation of percentage sizing. and i have implemented it. but its not how i want it to look.

to see an example :  https://admin.na3.acrobat.com/_a204547676/flextras/

sorry Jeffrey to use you as an example. :)

just try to resize your window and see it... thats what im looking for .

any hints guys?

Comment: just tried to resize like a hundred times and noticed that the resizing effect happens to the text too. percentage sizing does work but how do i apply it to all the other controls like label/checkbox etc hmm ...

Comment: It's Jeffry!  :-)  Show us the code you implemented and then tell us what it isn't doing.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code sample; the button is not given a height or width; so Flex sizes it automatically used a fixed width.  Give the button a percentage width or height and it should resize appropriately as the screen changes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">


 <s:BorderContainer width="40%" height="70%" y="10" horizontalCenter="0">
 <mx:Image height="100%" width="100%" id="img" source="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/ab/Apple-logo.png/125px-Apple-logo.png" horizontalCenter="0"/>

</s:BorderContainer>
<s:Button y="543" horizontalCenter="0" label="start" width="40%" height="30%"/>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i have tried it. but its not the result i am looking for.  if you keep resizing back and forth the acrobat app you can see the entire app resizing compared to the above example.

its not quite the same.